# Use VBA to get data from chart points in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a bubble chart in PowerPoint, and going to "Edit Data" doesn't work (an Excel process opens but the spreadsheet does not--I've tried the DLL registering at [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bgp/archive/2011/02/03/when-i-click-edit-data-on-a-2007-native-chart-nothing-happens.aspx), but it did not work). So I just want to loop through all the points in the chart with VBA and get the data associated (debug.print is fine). That includes three data values per point: x, y, and size. Unfortunately it appears PowerPoint just views it as one series of data--the y value. I set cht equal to the chart object, and then `sercol = cht.SeriesCollection`, and sercol.Count returns a value of 1. If I `set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)` and `vals = ser.Values`, I can loop through all and print the value of the y coordinate, but I can't figure out how to get to the x coordinate and size (`cht.SeriesCollection(2)` is not valid). Is there a way to get the other two data values associated with the point in the bubble chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I `set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)` and `vals = ser.Values`, I can loop through all and print the value of the y coordinate, but I can't figure out how to get to the x coordinate

```
Dim xVals as Variant
xVals = ser.XValues
Debug.Print Join(xVals, ", ")
```

> and size (`cht.SeriesCollection(2)` is not valid).

Not sure why you'd try that if the chart only has one series, this would raise an error (expectedly), subscript out of range.

For the Bubble sizes, the series has a `.BubbleSizes` property, which should return a string:

```
Dim bbls
bbls = ser.BubbleSizes
Debug.Print bbls
```

It may return an array in your case, if so, you'd just need to tweak it a little bit.

Comment: That XValues is exactly what I needed--thanks! On the size, a bubble chart has three values--x, y, and size (so it plots the point and then sizes the point based on that size value). If "Edit Data" worked, you'd see an Excel sheet with three values per row, and I'm trying to get to those values. So I kind of thought there'd be three SeriesCollections, but there is just one (and it aligns to the y value). I have since discovered the MarkerSize property, and though I haven't gotten it to work yet, I think I need to use that (I had been looking for a Size property, so I missed MarkerSize).

Comment: The `SeriesCollection` is a collection of the *series* in the chart, not a collection of attributesfor each series :) Each series consists of an XValues and YValues. I don't think `MarkerSize` is what you're looking for though.  Hold on I found out what you're looking for and I will revise :)

Comment: I think I'm getting it--so series is really the entire collection of data? Not individual series of data to make up the whole (I was viewing x as a series, y as a series, and size value as a series)? That width worked well! Thanks so much!

Comment: No... a *series* is a series.  the [`SeriesCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836171.aspx) is the collection of all `Series` objects in the chart.